# Can I travel within the US with only my Valid student visa

Tags: visas, air-travel, passports, domestic-travel

My Passport is in the British consulate, and I would like to pick it up personally without shipping. I still have my valid Visa in my expired passport. I'm wondering if I can travel with. I also have other national IDs

Comment: Where are you travelling from/to? What is your citizenship? What are these other items of ID that you hold?

Comment: And how are you traveling?

Answer (score 1):

No. A U.S. visa is not [an acceptable ID](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/acceptable-ids) for TSA. (And in general visas do not serve as IDs; they are to be used with a passport which is the ID.) Foreign national IDs are also not acceptable IDs.